# Django ORM group by calculation should return data if the foreign have no related data too

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

This is my models:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00
    )
    entry_for = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ledger_entry_for',
    )
```

For example, i have 400+ users but only 50 users have purchased multiple time

So i want total purchase amount user by user.

so this is my query is below:

```
purchase_user_wise = Purchase.objects.values(
            'entry_for'
        ).annotate(
            total_purchase=Sum('amount')
        )
```

Above query works nice and I return total amount user by user but the problem is: it only return those users calculation who have purchased at least one time or more than one time. and this query not returning all 400 users data.

I want, if any of the users don't have any purchase entry, it should return `0` and rest of the calculation should be works that way.

Can anyone help me how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the opposite way: query from the `User` object, and *annotate* the users:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.annotate(
    total_purschase=Sum('ledger_entry_for__amount')
)
```

This will return a queryset of `User` objects, and each `User` from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_purchase`.

If the user made no purchase, then the sum will be `None` (`NULL`). You can use a [**`Coalesce`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to use `0` instead:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

User.objects.annotate(
    total_purschase=Coalesce(Sum('ledger_entry_for__amount'), Value(0))
)
```